# Is the convex hull of product channels strictly contained in the set of all channels

Tags: convex-analysis, semidefinite-programming, quantum-information

For two finite dimensional Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H},\mathcal{H'}$ let $T(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{H'})$ be the set of all CPTP maps (quantum channels) $L(\mathcal{H})\to L(\mathcal{H}')$.

Let $\mathcal{H},\mathcal{H_1},\mathcal{H_2}$ be finite dimensional Hilbert spaces, I am wondering whether the convex hull of $T(\mathcal{H_1},\mathcal{H})\otimes T(\mathcal{H_2},\mathcal{H})$ is strictly contained in $T(\mathcal{H_1}\otimes\mathcal{H_2},\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{H})$ (it seems that it does but a proof eludes me).

If so, is there a way to express this set, or an as small as possible set containing this set, as the solution set of a linear matrix inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this set is strictly contained in the other.

Note that by the main body of your question you are asking whether or not the convex hull of **product channels** (not separable) is strictly contained in the set of all channels. Separable channels are defined as those for which their Kraus operators have a tensor product form.

To see a counterexample we can look at Example 6.21 from [1] you can find a free version on the author's website. Define a channel $\Phi$ by the action,
$$
\Phi(|i\rangle \langle j| \otimes |k \rangle \langle l|) = \begin{cases}
|i \rangle \langle i | \otimes |i \rangle \langle i | \qquad &\text{if } i=j \text{ and } k=l \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Now let us suppose we could write $\Phi = \sum_a p(a) \Phi_a \otimes \Psi_a$ (i.e. a convex combination of product channels). Well then we have for any normalized state $\rho$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Phi(|0\rangle \langle 0 | \otimes \rho) &= |0 \rangle \langle 0|\otimes |0\rangle \langle 0 | \\
&= \sum_a p(a) \Phi_a(|0\rangle\langle 0|) \otimes \Psi_a(\rho)
\end{aligned}
$$
and then taking the partial trace over the first subsystem we may conclude that
$$
\sum_a p(a) \Psi_a(\rho) = |0\rangle \langle 0|.
$$
However, if we repeat these steps with the input state $|1 \rangle \langle 1| \otimes \rho$ we will instead conclude that $\sum_a p(a) \Psi_a(\rho) = |1\rangle \langle 1 |$. Thus we run into a contradiction and our assumption that our channel can be written as a convex combination of product channels is false.

[1]: *Watrous, John*, [**The theory of quantum information**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/9781316848142), Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-1-107-18056-7/hbk; 978-1-316-84814-2/ebook). viii, 590 p. (2018). [ZBL1393.81004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1393.81004).